# Use sed or awk to find match and leave it in place but add it somewhere alse

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

Suppose I have a file with these lines:

```
"transition.fadeOut"
"transition.flipXOut"
"transition.whirlOut"
```

I would need to match `XXXX` and place it somewhere else on the line.

```
"transition.XXXX"=> __( 'XXXX', 'lorem-ipsum' ),
```

So the end result would look like this.

```
"transition.fadeOut"=> __( 'fadeOut', 'lorem-ipsum' ),
"transition.flipXOut"=> __( 'flipXOut', 'lorem-ipsum' ),
"transition.whirlOut"=> __( 'whirlOut', 'lorem-ipsum' ),
```

I've tried using grouping, but I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just an exercise on capturing groups and printing them back:

```
$ sed -r 's/^("[^.]*\.)([^"]*)"/\1\2"=> __( "\2", "lorem-ipsum" ),/' file
"transition.fadeOut"=> __( "fadeOut", "lorem-ipsum" ),
"transition.flipXOut"=> __( "flipXOut", "lorem-ipsum" ),
"transition.whirlOut"=> __( "whirlOut", "lorem-ipsum" ),
```

Comment: Oh, so you basically matched to whole line and divided it into groups. 
And than in substitution but the groups together in the proper order.

Comment: Exactly: `( ... )` captures a group and then `\1`, `\2`... print them back